How do I work with time-series data of temperature?
So I have some equipment temperature and i have outside temperature (both are collected daily) and I want to predict the equipment temperature. However, I'm new to this and unsure about which model to use. I've read about VAR, SVAR, Bayesian time series, and random forest models for time series forecasting, but I'm still uncertain about which one to choose.
Here is a plot of both series where the red curve is the outside temperature and the black one is the equipment temperature:

We can see that the equipment temperature has a similar curve to the outdoor one except when there is a failure or problem.
I've also considered using the outside temperature as the seasonal component of the equipment temperature time series, but I'm unsure if it's correct.
Here is what I tried for this :
# Create time series data frame
time_series <- data.frame(
  dateheure = merged_data$DATETIME,
  temp_eq = merged_data$TEMPERATURE,
  temp_ext = merged_data$TEMP
)

# Convert data to time series object including both temp_eq and temp_ext
time_series_ts <- ts(cbind(time_series$temp_eq, time_series$temp_ext), 
frequency = 365)

ts_data <- ts(time_series$temp_eq, frequency = 365)
seasonal_ts <- ts(time_series$temp_ext, frequency = 365)

model <- auto.arima(ts_data, xreg = seasonal_ts)
forecast <- forecast(model, xreg = seasonal_ts, h = 1)  

plot(forecast, xaxt = "n")
date_labels <- as.Date(data_site$DATETIME)
axis(1, at = time(ts_data), labels = date_labels)


Any help or links explaining this topic would be greatly appreciated!

I've also considered using the outside temperature as the seasonal component of the equipment temperature time series, but I'm unsure if it's correct.- "you may report your model and results."

@SubhashC.Davar updated as you asked

Is this failure you mentioned available as a  feature for your model?

Not yet. I need to get the alarms data and see how to add it.

Following Andrew Ng's approach to machine learning, "make a quick & dirty model."
When you're unsure on how to solve some prediction task (and there's no guiding literature on the problem you're working on), start out by trying all your ideas! Even if they are "quick & dirty", which often means that they are definitely unoptimized and perhaps even misguided.
However, you'll learn a lot more about which models you should pursue based on the intermediate outputs you generate.
You mentioned a few statistical models we can use for time series, try all of them out! Start with VAR and treat this as a baseline when comparing other models. Mean absolute error is a good metric to use.
Integrating seasonality into your analysis would be interesting as well. One thing to note is that seasonality of your equipment temp data must be expressed only in the equipment temp data. However, you could implement a dummy variable which represents seasonality of outside temps.
For example, in the R vars:VAR package, you can specify the season parameter as an integer value that represents the frequency of your season temps. So if your data was collected over the course of the year (Jan -> Dec) and you wanted to express the basic seasons you would use season=4.
Good luck!
